# MongoDB Aggregate Lookup and Unwind

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have this problem:

I need make a query, getting foreign data (by lookup), 'many to many' and 'one to many'.

My data looks so:

**Transfers collection:**

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "requests": [
    {
       "service": 1,
       "foo": "foo1",
       "bar": "bar1"
    },
    {
       "service": 2,
       "foo": "foo2",
       "bar": "bar2"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, the "service" field, is a foreign ID of another collection "services".

**Services collection:**

```
[{ _id: 1, name: 'Service 1" }, { _id: 2, name: 'Service 2' }]
```

The question is: How can I to filter by a service name, in the Transfer collection? I know mongoose's populate, but this doesn't allow to filter by a foreign data (Also, my function requires pagination (I use mongoose-pagination plugin), therefore, I discard to filter after execute, because that could filter from a little data universe).

The best option, I believe, is to use aggregate.
But, if I make this...

```
db.transfers.aggregate([
  { 
    $lookup: { 
      from: 'services', 
      localField: 'requests.service', 
      foreignField: '_id', 
      as: 'requests.service'
    } 
  }
])
```

I got this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "requests" : {
        "service" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : 1,
                "name" : "Service 1"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : 1,
                "name" : "Service 2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How I can put in service data inside the principal object without to alter the query?

Apparently, the aggregate function, adds a "unwind" on "requests" (many), but not on "service" (one)

Whatever, I need this returned data:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "requests": [
        {
           "service": {
                "_id" : 1,
                "name" : "Service 1"
            },
           "foo": "foo1",
           "bar": "bar1"
        },
        {
           "service": {
               "_id" : 2,
               "name" : "Service 2"
            },
           "foo": "foo2",
           "bar": "bar2"
        }
      ]
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to get service names to be included in each `request` object?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution - not sure just now if it's the prettiest possible but it certainly gets the job done:

```
db.transfers.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'services',
        localField: 'requests.service',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'requests2'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "requests": {
            $map: {
                "input": {
                    $zip: {
                        "inputs": [ "$requests", "$requests2" ]
                    }
                },
                "as": "this",
                "in": {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                        { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$this", 0 ] },
                        { "service": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$this", 1 ] } }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

The second option is to do this:

```
db.transfers.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'services',
        localField: 'requests.service',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'requests2'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "requests": {
            $map: {
                "input": {
                    $range: [ 0, { $size: "$requests2" } ]
                },
                "as": "index",
                "in": {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                        { $arrayElemAt: [ "$requests", "$$index" ] },
                        { "service": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$requests2", "$$index" ] } }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

I've never actually compared the performance of the two verions but I would suspect the second is a little bit faster.